# Do I need to `return` after `throw` in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, exception, error-handling

I'm throwing an `Error` from a method of mine that I want an early exit from, as below:

```
// No route found
if(null === nextRoute) {
    throw new Error('BAD_ROUTE');
}
```

Do I need to put a `return;` statement after my `throw`? It works for me, for now. If it's superfluous I'd rather not put it in, but I can't be sure what different browsers might do.

Answer (score 242, accepted):

You do not need to put a `return` statement after `throw`, the `return` line will never be reached as throwing an exception immediately hands control back to the caller.

Comment: "throwing an exception immediately hands control back to the caller"...
Unless there is a CATCH to handle the thrown error in any path of the call stack.

Comment: @Mahesh I'm not sure what you mean by "Unless" - any CATCH in the  stack underneath where the `throw` occurred is part of a "caller"

Comment: I've got a console.log after 'throw new Error()' line and this console.log is executing. So why is that?

Comment: tested in firefox 88.0 ubuntu 20.04. `throw` does terminate `function`.

Answer (score 3):

The throw statement throws a user-defined exception. Execution of **the current function will stop** (the statements after throw won't be executed), and control will be passed to the first catch block in the call stack. If no catch block exists among caller functions, the program will terminate.