# MongoDB not returning updated values

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-atlas

I am using MongoDB Atlas to host my MongoDB. My backend code is in Node.js and I'm using Mongoose.

All the documents in my collection have the same properties. I added one additional property manually to one document to test a new functionality.

I added the property protection_percentage with the value 3. I called my endpoint using Postman and got the value 3 as expected. No issues there.

I then updated the value manually to 5. I still get 3. I tested with another document, that doesn't have this property, and I still get protection_percentage:3 in the response.

I do not have any cache set up in my application. I can't seem to figure out why do I keep getting the old value, and then I get the value for an object that doesn't even have this property!

I would appreciate your help on this!

This is my code for getting the protection percentage:

```
const getProtectionPercentage = async (platformDomain) => {
  const store = await schema.findOne({ platform_domain: platformDomain });
  const { protection_percentage } = store || {};

  if (!store) {
    throw new Error(`No store found with platform_domain: ${platformDomain}`);
  }

  if (protection_percentage === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`Protection Percentage not set for the store: ${platformDomain}`);
  }

  return protection_percentage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After throwing error you should add a return to the function for not returning the old value at the last return.

```
const getProtectionPercentage = async (platformDomain) => {
  const store = await schema.findOne({ platform_domain: platformDomain });
  const { protection_percentage } = store || {};

  if (!store) {
    throw new Error(`No store found with platform_domain: ${platform_domain}`);
    return;

  }

  if (protection_percentage === undefined) {
    throw new Error(`Protection Percentage not set for the store: 
${platform_domain}`);
    return;
  }

  return protection_percentage;
}
```

Comment: You do not need to put a return statement after throw, the return line will never be reached as throwing an exception immediately hands control back to the caller. [Do I need to return after throw in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26067190/do-i-need-to-return-after-throw-in-javascript)

Comment: so although protection_percentage is undefined it jumps from "throw new Error"  and reaches the last return. - May be 2nd if statement should be like if(protection_percentage === undefined || null || ""){ }. Or try to get the protection_percentage  as const protectionPercentage= store?.protection_percentage

Comment: the first if statement will catch a undefined case